# Working with Multi Dimensional Array in Google Script

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet where the first row is the number of days. The second and third row is the daily production of different companies in those number of days. Its something like this.
[image]

My requirement is to get the number of days row and the a particular company production details row in a 2D array.

Here is my code.

```
function GetData()
 {
  myFunction("Konabay");
 }

 function myFunction(Company)
 {
   var dSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var aSheet= dSheet.getSheetByName("Data");
   var range = aSheet.getDataRange();
   var values = range.getValues();
   var VNeeded=[];

   for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
   {
   //var row = "";
   var companyCheck="No";

   for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) 
     {
       if (values[i][j]) 
         {
           if (i==0)//Need the first row(days) in my new array always
           {
             VNeeded[i,j]=values[i][j];
             Logger.log("VNeeded i=0 (0,3) = "+ VNeeded[0,3]);
             Logger.log("VNeeded i=0(1,3)= "+ VNeeded[1,3]);
             //row = row + values[i][j];
           }
           else if (i>0)//From second row onwards check for the company needed
           {
             if(values[i][0]==Company)
             {
               companyCheck="Yes";
             }
             if(companyCheck=="Yes")
             {
               VNeeded[i,j]=values[i][j];
               Logger.log("VNeeded i>0 (0,3) = "+ VNeeded[0,3]);
               Logger.log("VNeeded i>0 (1,3)= "+ VNeeded[1,3]);
               //row = row + values[i][j];
             }
           }

         }
      //row = row + ",";
     }
      //Logger.log(row);

 }
}
```

I was looking for some thing like this

VNeeded[] =[10,2.5],[30,4],[40,5],[30,5]

But what i am getting is

VNeeded[] =[2.5,2.5],[4,4],[5,5],[5,5]

to check what is going on i used the Logger.log and it gave  this  result.

```
[18-01-28 22:36:30:121 IST] VNeeded i=0 (0,3) = undefined
[18-01-28 22:36:30:122 IST] VNeeded i=0(1,3)= undefined
[18-01-28 22:36:30:123 IST] VNeeded i=0 (0,3) = undefined
[18-01-28 22:36:30:123 IST] VNeeded i=0(1,3)= undefined
[18-01-28 22:36:30:124 IST] VNeeded i=0 (0,3) = undefined
[18-01-28 22:36:30:124 IST] VNeeded i=0(1,3)= undefined
[18-01-28 22:36:30:125 IST] VNeeded i=0 (0,3) = 30
[18-01-28 22:36:30:126 IST] VNeeded i=0(1,3)= 30
[18-01-28 22:36:30:126 IST] VNeeded i=0 (0,3) = 30
[18-01-28 22:36:30:127 IST] VNeeded i=0(1,3)= 30
[18-01-28 22:36:30:127 IST] VNeeded i>0 (0,3) = 30
[18-01-28 22:36:30:128 IST] VNeeded i>0 (1,3)= 30
[18-01-28 22:36:30:128 IST] VNeeded i>0 (0,3) = 30
[18-01-28 22:36:30:129 IST] VNeeded i>0 (1,3)= 30
[18-01-28 22:36:30:130 IST] VNeeded i>0 (0,3) = 30
[18-01-28 22:36:30:130 IST] VNeeded i>0 (1,3)= 30
[18-01-28 22:36:30:131 IST] VNeeded i>0 (0,3) = 5
[18-01-28 22:36:30:132 IST] VNeeded i>0 (1,3)= 5
[18-01-28 22:36:30:132 IST] VNeeded i>0 (0,3) = 5
[18-01-28 22:36:30:133 IST] VNeeded i>0 (1,3)= 5
```

So where am i getting it wrong??
When i am setting values to VNeeded[1,3], the same value is being set to the other dimension (VNeeded[0,3]) too. How is that possible?

Please help me get out of this issue.

How can i get the desired result. What am i doing wrong

The link to my test sheet is : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15hOjIr11Czf1KtrvEgo00pvE0kc7fMfSvRhmrn1tPBM/edit?usp=sharing

Please help

```
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(VNeeded)) gives this result :  ["Konabay",2.5,4,5,5]
```

Comment: Logger.log(JSON.stringify(VNeeded)) give this result :
[18-01-29 17:43:17:975 IST] ["Konabay",2.5,4,5,5]

Comment: Once the row of a selected company is over,the variable is re-decleared to default value "No" as the loop moves to the top. So it doesnt seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reference to an array position `VNeeded[i,j]` is not giving you the result you expect. In effect, you are passing an array of position integer into `VNeeded` which will resolve to the last figure. i.e. `VNeeded[j]`

Use `VNeeded[i][j]` instead.

```
VNeeded[i][j]=values[i][j];
```

**HOWEVER!**

This will throw an error in your code because the "array" at position i you are trying to put a value in at position 'j' doesn't exist. So, you'll need to prefill the position with an array if required:

```
VNeeded[i] = VNeeded[i] || [];
VNeeded[i][j] = values[i][j];
```

**HOWEVER!**

to get the result you required:

> `[10,2.5],[30,4],[40,5],[30,5];`

You need to switch `VNeeded[i][j]` to  `VNeeded[j][i]` in both parts of your row conditional check.

```
VNeeded[j] = VNeeded[i] || [];
VNeeded[j][i] = values[i][j];
```

Because what you are trying is in effect a filter on a pivot, your code could be much simplified by performing the pivot, first, checking the position of the company in the list and returning the pair of results that way:

```
function getData(company) {

  var dSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var aSheet= dSheet.getSheetByName("Data");
  var range = aSheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var vNeeded=[];
  var pivotedData = []; // Used to carry the transposed data

  for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i += 1) {
    for (var j = 0, k = data[i].length; j < k; j += 1) {    
      pivotedData[j] = pivotedData[j] || []; // allows for entry into preexisting array.
      pivotedData[j][i] = data[i][j];
    }
  }

  var companyIndex = pivotedData[0].indexOf(company); // find company in the list

  if (companyIndex < 0) return; // There is no matching company, returns undefined

  for (var i = 1, l = pivotedData.length; i < l; i += 1) { 
    vNeeded[i-1] = [pivotedData[i][0], pivotedData[i][companyIndex]]; // [expected,found]
  }
  return vNeeded;
}
```

Comment: Thanks indeed. That was very much helpful

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript `VNeeded[i,j]` evaluates to `VNeeded[j]` because of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Use `VNeeded[i][j]` instead.

I had to paste the code in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ to realise the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the array using this function:

```
function flattenArray(array){
var flatArray = []
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    flatArray.push(array[i][0])
  }
  return flatArray
}
```