# Tabular data manipulation in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, tabular

I'd like to be able to import data from different spreadsheets, do some arbitrarily complex operations on it programmatically (filtering, averaging, removing/adding columns, etc) and then save it back to the main spreadsheet.

I'm already able to import data from other spreadsheets, but I am currently manipulating it with loops as arrays of arrays (low level operations).

In python I would use something like pandas dataframes to manipulate the tabular data.
Is there a class in Google Apps Script that exposes functionality similar to that? Allowing for filtering, appending, row/column-wise operations, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in method to handle tabular data (aka, nested arrays, 2d arrays, range values) in Google Apps Script, but the Array.prototype  methods might help, just you have to learn to use them with nested Arrays Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Related

- [Sort Range Values without sorting the spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25623462/1595451)
- [Working with Multi Dimensional Array in Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48500630/1595451)
- [How to perform Cartesian Join with Google Scripts & Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65556675/1595451)